# array data is not being sent to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this schema for my project but it is not pushing the data in mongo db

```
let bracketModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    tournamentName: String,
    gameType: String,
    players: Number,
    description: String,
    teams: [String],
  },

  {
    collection: "bracketsample",
  }
);
```

here is my function

```
module.exports.addprocesspage = (req, res, next) => {
  
  let newbracket = Bracket({    
    
    tournamentName: req.body.tournamentName,
    gameType: req.body.gameType,
    players: req.body.players,
    description: req.body.description,
    $addToset:{teams:[req.body.teams]},
  });
  Bracket.create(newbracket, (err, Bracket) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end(err);
    } else {
      //refresh the bracket-list
      res.redirect("/bracket-list");
      console.log();
    }
  });
};
```

tried declaring cons varialble=req.body.teams but still not working.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What does the content of `req.body.teams` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "new" syntax before "Bracket". Also you use the create method with the already created "Bracket", i would use save instead. Try this:

```
let newBracket = new Bracket({    
   tournamentName: req.body.tournamentName,
   gameType: req.body.gameType,
   players: req.body.players,
   description: req.body.description,
   $addToset:{teams:[req.body.teams]},
});

newBracket.save().then(() => {
    res.redirect("/bracket-list");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.end(err);
});
```